# Bandwidth throttling / simulation for selected host

Tags: macos, network, performance

I can control the network for the whole device with Network Link Conditioner but is there a way to do it just for selected hosts? I know that with /etc/hosts I can totally block connection to a host, but it's not what I need here. As a minimum solution, if I were able to make a host never respond, but just keeps loading forever, it would work, too.

Comment: I’m curious why you want this. Is it bandwidth control you want or high error rates?

Comment: I have a web app && browser extension and I would like to observe how it behaves, and if there is any impact on the app in case the analytics service is responding slowly. I've got a bug report that indicates there might be.

Answer (score 0):

I make a VM when I need this and only install the conditioner on the VM. It’s usually no hassle for me to have the entire computer slow or lossy when I’m testing and then I return it to full performance when I’m done.

I suppose it depends on why you are wanting to have differential speeds out of the same network interface.  It’s really a lot of complexity to poke holes in the filter when it’s implemented on a per interface basis. I’m curious what your use case is for not just doing the testing and returning your network interface to full speed.